# PHP : could not find driver (PDO, MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php

error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE );
ob_start();
session_start();

define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'db_test');

define('PROJECT_NAME', 'Testing create');
$dboptions = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAME utf8',
    );

try{
    $DB = new PDO(DB_SERVER. ':host='.DB_SERVER. ';dbname='.DB_DATABASE,DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD , $dboptions);
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
    die;
}

require_once 'functions.php';

if($_SESSION["errorType"] != "" && $_SESSION["errorMsg"] != "" ){
    $ERROR_TYPE = $_SESSION["errorType"];
    $ERROR_MSG = $_SESSION["errorMsg"];
    $_SESSION["errorType"] = "";
    $_SESSION["errorMsg"] = "";
}

?>
```

The code above give error "could not find driver". I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.thesoftwareguy.in/creating-multi-user-role-based-admin-using-php-mysql-bootstrap/) to create them, downloaded their source code and view on browser, no error at all. But when im trying to create my program based on their, i got the error. FYI my PDO extension is enable, checked it twice.

What is wrong with my code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct the $DB to:

```
$DB = new PDO(DB_DRIVER. ':host='.DB_SERVER. ';dbname='.DB_DATABASE,DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD , $dboptions);
```

Here is sample that easier to understand

```
$db = new PDO('dblib:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
```

Comment: successfully remove the error. but another problem appear, my page connected to this connection load like forever. do i need to change the whole codes?

Comment: you can try to remove this line "require_once 'functions.php';". Does it still happen?

Comment: so far it's going smoothly, i'll accept yours as answer